# Set p datatable header

Tags: java, primefaces, facelets

I have the following datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{openReportBean.rows}" var="row">                                      
    <p:columns value="#{openReportBean.columns}" var="col">
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{row[col].columnName}
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row[col]}"/>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

The problem is the column headers are set in the row variable, I can access them using row.columnName but they are not displayed.
Can I do anything about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that correct definition of your header should be:

```
<f:facet name="header">
        #{col.columnName}
</f:facet>
```

or reconsider having method in your backing bean that returns column name and then just call it in `<f:facet name="header">`

Comment: Unfortunately col doesn't store the column names, only the object's attributes that will be displayed

Comment: Then you can maybe define some method in your bean that will return column name. And call that method in `<f:facet name="header">`